# Generating an emoji from unicode and then extracting unicode gives a different unicode

Tags: javascript, unicode, emoji

[image]

one and two are created with different uni-codes.

But they give the same emoji.

Now the interesting point is Unicode from one is completely a different value.

```js
one = String.fromCodePoint(parseInt("1f436",16))
two = String.fromCodePoint(parseInt("d83d",16),parseInt("dc36",16))
one === two
one.length
one.codePointAt(0).toString(16) + '-' + one.codePointAt(1).toString(16)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code point values range from U+0000 to U+10FFFF.

---

Initially JavaScript had `Unicode escape sequences` which consist of exactly 4 hexadecimal digits to represent a code point. U+0000 to U+FFFF could be represented using these.

eg:

```js
>> 'I \u2661 JavaScript!'
'I ♡ JavaScript!'
```

---

In ES6, JS introduced `Unicode code point escapes`.

```js
>> '\u{1F4A9}'
'' // U+1F4A9 PILE OF POO
```

Between the braces, you can use up to six hexadecimal digits, which is enough to represent all Unicode code points.

For backward compatibility with ECMAScript 5 and older environments, the unfortunate solution is to use surrogate pairs:

```
>> '\uD83D\uDCA9'
'' // U+1F4A9 PILE OF POO
```

ECMAScript 6 introduces `String.prototype.codePointAt(position)` which would deal with surrogate halves whenever possible and returns the hex.

```
>> ''.codePointAt(0)
0x1F4A9
```

---

source : https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode

video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zi0w7J7MCrk